# Select highest Age where Age is closest to a number

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Think I have been looking at my code too much.

But my problems is that I have a unordered list and I need to select the object with the highest number closes to or equals an input.

I have created this little sample to illustrate what I trying to do.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Age = 10, Name = "Aaron"},
    new Person {Age = 15, Name = "Alice"},
    new Person {Age = 20, Name = "John"},
    new Person {Age = 22, Name = "Bob"},
    new Person {Age = 24, Name = "Malcom"}
};

int i = 17; //should return 'Alice 15'    
int y = 22; //should return 'Bob 22
```

Comment: Would 21 return John or Bob? Would 13 return Aaron or Alice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var person = persons.Where(p => p.Age <= input).OrderByDecending(p => p.Age).First();
```

This first excludes the ones that are greater than `input` (your `i` or `y`). Then starts to sort them, then it just takes the first result.

Comment: You can replace `OrderByDecending(p => p.Age).First()` with `Max(p => p.Age)`, which is simpler and more intent revealing.

Comment: @abatishchev - it depends on intent.

Comment: @Steven - no that will just return the maximum age, not the `Person`

Comment: @DanielA.White: You're right. He wanted the person, not the age.

Answer (score 3):

More efficient than sorting the entire collection (which might be expensive on a large input collection) using the MoreLinq project's [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs):

```
var person = persons.Where(p => p.Age <= input)
                    .MaxBy(p => p.Age);
```

Comment: MaxBy() is a member of Jon Skeet's [morelinq library](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var nearest = persons.OrderBy(p => Math.Abs(p.Age - i)).First();
```

This returns the person which age is nearest to the input value using [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the absolute difference.

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Then OP has changed the requirement since i've still a copy of his sample data here with following comment: `int i = 14; //should return 'Alice 15'`.

Comment: Then all that has to happen is clips any people with an age greater than the number. A simple fix.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: I'm not sure if i understand. Yes, i could easily fix it, but i assume that others have already posted the correct solution. I keep it though, maybe OP will change his opinion again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You traverse the list and store the absolute value of your int minus the Age. Store the Person in a variable until somebody with less difference shows up. If the same, store the one with the higher Age. Done.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example i have, it should help you

```
     List<int> list = new List<int> { 10, 15, 20, 22, 24 };
        int number = 17;
        int closest = list.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - number) < Math.Abs(y - number) ? x : y);
        Label2.Text = closest.ToString();
```